# Using Win32 TextOut to draw text at an angle

Tags: winapi, text, rotation, gdi

I'm using GDI to draw text onto a device context, and I noticed that the kerning or character placement is different if the angle is exactly 0, 90, 180, or 270. As soon as I increase the angle by 1, the character placement differs noticeably.

Rather than creating an `HFONT` with the angle, I am using `ModifyWorldTransform` to transform the device context's world coordinates, and then I use `TextOut` to draw the text onto the device context.

I think that GDI is using font hints or some other special technique when the text is being drawn at exact multiples of 90 degrees, but not for any other angle.

Is there a way to disable this hinting, so that text rendered at 0 degrees does not differ significantly from text rendered at 1 degree?

Here's an example of what I mean (Monotype Corsiva font):

**0 degrees**:
[image: 0 degrees]

**1 degree**:
[image: 1 degree]

For some fonts, such as Arial or Tahoma, it is not as noticeable, but I would like to get rid of the difference entirely, even if it means the text is not rendered as best it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to anti-aliasing rather than font hints. You could try the following:

- Disable (font) AA, but this will not yield acceptable results.
- Create font handles for every possible angle and see if the problem persists. I assume it doesn't, but it's not a pretty solution.
- Render the text to a bitmap (e.g. using `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` ) render the text to it and then render the rotated bitmap. This depends on how often you need different rotations / different text.
- Play with `fdwOutputPrecision` and `fdwQuality` in `CreateFont()`. This could be the easiest solution, but you'd have to experiment a little bit I guess.

hth

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but unfortunately even if I disable AA, the result is the same (except the text is not anti-aliased). If I fiddle with the precision/quality of CreateFont it doesn't change the result either :( I think I'll just have to put up with it for now and fix it when it management asks me to.